# How can I use get-date to change the month while controlling the format in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I just started working with Powershell and I am trying to manipulate a date such that I add two months to the date and set it as a var.  Powershell handles this nicely and even handles year rollover.  However I am stuck trying to figure out how to also control the format of the date before, during or after adding two months to the date.  Both of the statements below give me what I want but i have not been able to figure out how to combine them.

$ndate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(2)

$exp = date -format MM/dd/yyyy

Thank you,

Answer (score 10):

```
Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(2) -f MM/dd/yyyy
```

When the -Format operator is not avaiable you can use the ToString method:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(2).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```